# IBM DB2 connection from docker through python throwing [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, db2

I have tried multiple docker images including centos7, centos8, debian, python, ubuntu.
But every where its a dead end.
I am able to connect from node js from same docker build.
Even using python it is successfully connecting to db2 from windows but when I use python in docker it fails with License error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 493, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/service/ibm_db_dbi.py", line 1188, in connect
    raise _get_exception(inst)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: Exception('[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-1598')
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM python

USER root
WORKDIR /home/service
ADD ./ /home/service

RUN python --version
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN cp db2consv_ee.lic /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clidriver/license/
```

**requirements.txt**

```
ibm_db==3.0.2
ibm-db-sa==0.3.5
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
```

**Python script**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("db2+ibm_db://userId:password@host:port/db") #create a database engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
metadata = MetaData(schema='schemaName')
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine, metadata=metadata)

class Customers(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'tableName'
   CLIENT_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   CLIENT_NAME = Column(Integer)
   CREATED_BY = Column(String)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = Session()
result = session.query(Customers).limit(2)

for row in result:
   print (row.CLIENT_NAME )
```

Comment: What Db2 product are you trying to connect to? What is the Python code, how do you connect? Why do you need that license file? The Db2 driver does not need it

Comment: Updated the question with python scripts

Comment: Run a CLI trace inside the docker image when attempting the connection via the `db2cli` tool (needs a fully configured db2dsdriver.cfg) and temporarily eliminate python.  (see Db2 Knowledge Centre for details of how to do that cli tracing) to see what is going on under the covers . Format the output of the clitrace and study it carefully.   Confirm you are connecting to Db2-for-Z/OS.  It may be wiser to arrange with your Z DBA to configure the target subsystem to be enabled for db2connectactivate (to eliminate client side licensing).

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with python, it is a configuration matter for clidriver only. Sometimes you get this symptom when the version of the license-file  is incompatible with the version of the target subsystem. But other causes are possible, hence the need to study the cli trace.

Comment: driver is installed while installing ibm_db using pip install ibm_db.
Then I copied the licence file clidriver license folder.

Comment: This is self evident from your question. Suggest you configure your `db2dsdriver.cfg` correctly in the container (or prepopulate it), validate it with `db2cli validate` , and run a `db2trc on -f dumpfile` followed by `db2cli validate - connect -dsn XXX -user YYY -passwd ZZZ`, the use `db2trc` to turn off trace and fmt the dumpfile to text files and study them to see what is really happening.  This is basic problem determination.

Comment: It generates file in non readable format

                      3                                                   c^����  ��         �7"��    E ���������                   a^����  ��         �7"��    D ���������                   `^����  ��         �7"��    A ��������   d
                                                                           _^����  ��         �7"��    A ���������   � O                    G   SQL10007N
Message "90016" could not be retrieved.  Reason code:
"3". .                                             ]^����  ��         �7"��

Comment: command used 
./db2trc on -f dumpfile followed by
./db2cli validate -database "DB:host:port" -connect -user userid -passwd psswd followed by
./db2trc off

Comment: As per documentation, It is necessary to format the dumpfile via various options to `db2trc` like `fmt` and `flw` etc , which then produce readable text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the packages like npm or pip fetches the driver from https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ .
And they randomly update the file without maintaining the versions.
All the versions are maintained in https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/323035
Their is some issue with latest version of clidriver(11.5) which is mapped to the link
https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/

Instead, I am able to resolve it by downloading 11.1 version from https://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm11116777

For linux downloaded as there are no 64bit driver for odbc-cli so downloaded **IBM Data Server Runtime Client** [Linux x86](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/quickorder?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation%20Management%2FIBM%20Data%20Server%20Client%20Packages&release=11.1.*&platform=Linux%2064-bit,x86_64&searchtype=fix&fixids=*rtcl*FP005) and extracted the v11.1.4fp5_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz and replaced *node_modules/ibm_db/installer/* and */usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/* with v11.1.4fp5_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz\v11.1.4fp5_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar\dsdriver\odbc_cli_driver\linuxamd64\

For windows : **IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (64-bit)** and replaced *node_modules/ibm_db/installer/* and */usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/* with [Windows 64bit](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/quickorder?source=dbluesearch&product=ibm%2FInformation%20Management%2FIBM%20Data%20Server%20Client%20Packages&release=11.1.*&platform=Windows%2064-bit,%20x86&searchtype=fix&fixids=*odbc_cli-*FP005)

Comment: what kind of issue you are facing with clidriver(11.5)? Please open an issue in github repo with details. 11.5 clidriver works fine for other users. Thanks.

Comment: Now version is maintained at https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ as v11.1.4, v11.5.4, v11.5.5, v11.5.6. Also this clidriver download is only for automatic download by open source drivers. If you want to download a db2 client manually, then download it from official site https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-db2-fix-packs-version-db2-linux-unix-and-windows. But, do not download clidriver from this site as it will not work with open source driver. Recommended driver is IBM Data Server Driver Package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQL1598N is due to use of db2 v11.1 license file that you are using to connect to Db2 for z/OS or Db2 for iSeries. The new ibm_db driver requires db2 v11.5 db2connect license to connect to z/OS and iSeries servers.
So, simple way to solve SQL1598N error is to upgrade the license file. If you open the db2consv_*.lic file in an editor, you can see the version is mentioned in it.
If you want to continue with existing v11.1 license, need to follow below steps:

1. Download https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz
2. untar it, you'll get clidriver directory.
3. export IBM_DB_HOME=<full_path_of_clidriver>
4. copy v11.1 db2consv_*.lic file under clidriver/license directory
5. pip install ibm_db

It should work fine now. Thanks.

Comment: I dont see v11.1 db2consv_*.lic file under clidriver/license directory ..

Comment: db2consv_*.lic file is a db2connect license file that you need to get from IBM support. This file do not come with clidriver. License is not free.
Also, this license file is not required if DB2 for z/OS server is db2connect activated by your system admin. Thanks.